# How can I find a reference to an object using javascript if I know the id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I used the following HTML:

```
<textarea style="height: 350px; width: 100%"
   data-ck-editor="text" id="editor-1"
   data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
   data-ng-model="modal.data.text"></textarea>
```

And this Directive:

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);
            ...
            ...
```

Now this is set up I would like to send a command to the ckEditor from my javascript outside of the directive. Like this:

```
editor1.setData('xxx');
```

How can I find the ckEditor object (for example editor1) knowing that the directive that created it was based on a textarea with an id="editor-1" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store all editor instances in a service, which would be accessible from everywhere else. The code might look like this:

```
app.value("ckEditors", {});

app.directive('ckEditor', ["ckEditors", function (ckEditors) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            ckEditors[attr.id] = ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);
            ...
            ...

app.controller('somectrl', function (ckEditors) {
    ckEditors["editor-1"].setData('xxx')
    ...
```

Event though I don't know your reason behind direct ckEditor access from outside directive, I'm sure there are more elegant solutions than this.